# How to get the product of a tuple of ints with variable number of arguments?

Tags: generics, f#, constraints

```
type TotalSizeToken = TotalSizeToken with
    static member TotalSize(_: TotalSizeToken, (a,b,c,d,e)): int = a*b*c*d*e
    static member TotalSize(_: TotalSizeToken, (a,b,c,d)): int = a*b*c*d
    static member TotalSize(_: TotalSizeToken, (a,b,c)): int = a*b*c
    static member TotalSize(_: TotalSizeToken, (a,b)): int = a*b
    static member TotalSize(_: TotalSizeToken, x: int): int = x

let inline size_to_total_size x = 
    ((^s) : (static member TotalSize: TotalSizeToken * ^s -> int) TotalSizeToken, x)

let t = size_to_total_size (1,5) // Error: Expecting a type supporting the operator TotalSize, but given a tuple type.
```

I had not expected the `x` argument in `size_to_total_size` to require the TotalSize member. This feels like a compiler bug.

I am not sure how to get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the other 'hat' type:

```
let inline size_to_total_size x = 
    let call (t:^T) = ((^s or ^T) : (static member TotalSize: TotalSizeToken * ^s -> int) t, x)
    call TotalSizeToken
```

There must be two of them, the argument being passed and the one that represents the class containing the overloads.

Otherwise it will never look into the class, only in the tuple and there is no such method in the tuple type.

Answer (score 1):

```
type TotalSizeToken<'u> = TotalSizeToken of 'u with
    static member TotalSize(x: TotalSizeToken<int*int*int*int*int>): int = 
        match x with TotalSizeToken (a,b,c,d,e) -> a*b*c*d*e
    static member TotalSize(x: TotalSizeToken<int*int*int*int>): int = 
        match x with TotalSizeToken (a,b,c,d) -> a*b*c*d
    static member TotalSize(x: TotalSizeToken<int*int*int>): int = 
        match x with TotalSizeToken (a,b,c) -> a*b*c
    static member TotalSize(x: TotalSizeToken<int*int>): int = 
        match x with TotalSizeToken (a,b) -> a*b
    static member TotalSize(x: TotalSizeToken<int>): int = 
        match x with TotalSizeToken x -> x

let inline size_to_total_size x = 
    ((^s) : (static member TotalSize: ^s -> int) x)

let t = size_to_total_size (TotalSizeToken(1,5))
```

This alternate form works. There is some extra boxing, but on the plus side, I won't need to pass around lambdas everywhere. Strangely enough it does not work if `size_to_total_size`is written like `let inline size_to_total_size x = ((^s) : (static member TotalSize: TotalSizeToken< ^s> -> int) x)` instead.